# Vaadin custom error message

Tags: java, vaadin

The Vaadin web framework displays a red error alert for any uncaught exceptions:

> Internal error
>
> Please notify the administrator
>
> ...

The Vaadin documentation describes [how to set a custom error handler](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.errors.html).

When I provide a custom error handler, the default red error alert still shows up. When the user dismisses that error alert, then the custom error alert appears. I would like to only show the custom error alert. How can one disable the default "Internal error" alert?

Below is the overridden terminalError method of my vaadin Application class:

```
@Override   public void terminalError(Terminal.ErrorEvent event) {
    // Call the default implementation.
    super.terminalError(event);

    // Some custom behaviour.
    if (getMainWindow() != null) {
        getMainWindow().showNotification(
                "An unchecked exception occured!",
                event.getThrowable().toString(),
                Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do both actions happens because you call `super.terminalError(event)`?

Or do you have to clear the component error that is [set in this method](http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/releases/6.6.6/src/com/vaadin/Application.java#L1190)?

Comment: Even if I comment-out the call to super.terminalError(event) it shows the built-in "Internal error"

Comment: When I use the terminalError(Terminal.ErrorEvent event) method used in the link you posted, it still displays the built-in "Internal error"

Comment: No sorry. I referenced the method to show you that it was setting a component error. My question was can you remove/clear that error? Like `setComponentError(null)`.

Comment: The setComponentError has no effect. I noticed that sometimes I do get the custom error dialog, and other times the built-in "Internal error" dialog. The custom error dialog appears when an Exception gets thrown from within a Button.ClickListener inner-class. But when an exception gets thrown from within a DefaultAbsoluteLayoutDropHandler inner-class, the built-in dialog appears

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a static method called **getSystemMessages** in your Application class, which will return a **CustomizedSystemMessages** object. If you call **setInternalErrorNotificationEnabled** method with false parameter "internal error" will disappear. This way you can disable Vaadin's built-in notification messages for other error types as well.

You can provide a url by calling **setInternalErrorURL** so that Vaadin will redirect your page to that url whenever internal error occurs. You can display your error message in that page. This page could be a Vaadin window as well.

Answer (score 0):

Paul is right : you have to remove the call to the super.

To work, I did the following in my subclass of Application :

```
setErrorHandler(this); // dont know why it's doesn't work without this instruction.
```

and I override the terminalError method without the call to `super.terminalError()`.

Regards, Éric

Comment: I have taken out the call to super.terminalError(event) and also set setErrorHandler(this); in the init() method.  It still displays the built-in "Internal error" message. My terminalError method does get call, because I can see its log statement